# Why does this JS not work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, toggle

I'm trying to calculate the size of 3 elements and if they're greater than the window height, apply another class to a 4 element.

This is what I have so far:

```
var limit = $(".logo").height() + $(".nav-items").height() + $(".nav-footer").height();
var win = $(window).height();
    $(document).ready(function(checkHeight) {
        if (limit > win) {
            var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-column");
            element.classList.toggle("red");
    }
});
```

Update:

I would like to apply the check to an existing function - I am VERY NEW to all this, thank you for your patients.

```
function aboutUssubNav() {
    var element = document.getElementById("about-us");
    element.classList.toggle("open");
    var element = document.getElementById("about-us-button");
    element.classList.toggle("open");
    // Check Height of Sidebar Elements to position Sidebar Footer
    var limit = $(".logo").height() + $(".nav-items").height() + $(".nav-footer").height();
    var win = $(window).height();
    if (limit > win) {
         var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-column");
         element.classList.toggle("red");
    }
}
```

Comment: did you import jquery min js url ?

Comment: _Why does this JS not work?_ Please state in your question, what doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are the limit value on `document.ready` event which is **unlikely to get fired again** during the life cycle of your page.

Simply remove the `document.ready` and make it

```
var limit = $(".logo").height() + $(".nav-items").height() + $(".nav-footer").height();
var win = $(window).height();
if (limit > win) {
     var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-column");
     element.classList.toggle("red");
}
```

Comment: Should this work?

function aboutUssubNav() {
        var element = document.getElementById("about-us");
        element.classList.toggle("open");
        var element = document.getElementById("about-us-button");
        element.classList.toggle("open");
        var limit = $(".logo").height() + $(".nav-items").height() + $(".nav-footer").height();
        var win = $(window).height();
        if (limit > win) {
             var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-column");
             element.classList.toggle("red");
        }
    }

Comment: @AOrigin sorry, I am unable to read your code from comments. Is it different from your original question? If no, Can you create a working snippet to replicate your issue

Comment: I've updated it above for you, thank you.

Comment: As I have stated earlier, please share a working snippet to demonstrate your issue. From your code it is impossible to make out what is not working. Also, it looks like that your earlier problem seems to be fixed, so raise a new question for new problem

Answer (score 0):

Just include the variables inside $(document).ready() function. 
Something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var limit = $(".logo").height() + $(".nav-items").height() + $(".nav-footer").height();
        var win = $(window).height();
        if (limit > win) {
            var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-column");
            element.classList.toggle("red");
        }
    });
```